# Get name of variable calling method from within that method

Tags: c#

I want to create an extension method for objects that check to see if the object is null and throw an exception if it is. I want to keep the original variable name though. Can I somehow get it from within the extension method? It is "cumbersome" to have to write `customer.NotNull("customer")`vs `customer.NotNull()`.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking for, then "no, you can't do that..."

Comment: And if I understood correctly, Why in the world do you want to create such a method? Isn't customer != null sufficient for you? It will avoid a function call overhead and can work with new operators like ?? and old ones like && and ||.

Comment: This would be a bad practice.

Comment: You might be missing the point of `Extension Methods`...

Comment: The reason for the extension method would to be able to write 'customer.NotNull()' instead of 'f (customer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("customer")'.
1: Why is that a bad practice?
2: How have I missed the point of Extension methods?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately you can't. Variable names are not part available at run time. However, you can use expressions like this:

```
void NotNull<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    var me = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    var name = me.Member.Name;
    var value = expression.Compile().Invoke();
    ...
}


NotNull(() => customer);
```

Comment: Why not an extension method like: public static class NotNullExtension { public static bool NotNull(this object obj) { return obj != null; } }

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It looks like that's what OP has already written. But you can't determine the name of the variable it is called on, which I presume is precisely why OP asked the question.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: It's somewhat unusual to create an extension method that only does something when its `this` object reference is `null`. Usually, the runtime will throw an `NullReferenceException` for `obj.SomeMethod(…)` when `obj` is `null`; in this case, it would throw (I guess) an `ArgumentNullException`, so such an extension method would deviate from standard / expected behavior... even though it would admittedly be very handy!

Answer (score 0):

As the other said, but note that compiling an expression is something slow... So this variant receives the value as a parameter. You have to write more, but for methods that are called hundred of times, it could be better.

```
[DebuggerHidden]
public static void NotNull<T>(T value, Expression<Func<T>> exp) where T : class
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var body = exp.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (body == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Wrongly formatted expression");
    }

    throw new ArgumentNullException(body.Member.Name);
}
```

Usage:

```
NotNull(str, () => str);
```

The `[DebuggerHidden]` is so that the debugger won't step into the method. In the end if the method throws, normally it's because what you passed, not what there is in the method.